# Return a value from procedure via the stack

Tags: assembly, stack, procedure

I'm learning assembly and I have to write a procedure (function) which gets a number and returns `1` if it's an even number and `0` if it's not.

I have to return the answer not via a register or flags, but via the stack (e.g. I can't put the answer in `bx` or `ax` and check their value in the main program). How can I do that?

Comment: The answer very much depends on the calling convention used, and it's a good thing to be aware of this. A function using the stack in such a way has a very particular calling convention, so both the function and the caller should be written with extra care.

Answer (score 3):

Next program was made with EMU8086 Intel syntax (just copy, paste and run), this is what it does : displays a message, captures a number from keyboard, converts the number from string to numeric, checks if number is even or odd, stores '1' or '0' in stack, and displays a message depending on '1' or '0'. Here it is, plenty of comments to help you understand :

```
.stack 100h
;------------------------------------------
.data
msj1  db 13,10,'Enter the number: $'
msj2  db 13,10,'The number is even$'
msj3  db 13,10,'The number is odd$'
str   db 6 ;MAX NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ALLOWED (5).
      db ? ;LENGTH (NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER).
      db 6 dup (?) ;CHARACTERS ENTERED BY USER. 
;------------------------------------------
.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

;DISPLAY MESSAGE.
  call clear_screen  ;DECLARED AT THE END OF THIS CODE.
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset msj1
  int  21h

;CAPTURE NUMBER FROM KEYBOARD AS STRING.
  mov  ah, 0Ah
  mov  dx, offset str
  int  21h

;CONVERT CAPTURED NUMBER FROM STRING TO NUMERIC.
  mov  si, offset str ;PARAMETER FOR STRING2NUMBER.
  call string2number ;NUMBER RETURNS IN BX. 

;CALL PROC TO FIND OUT IF NUMBER IS EVEN OR ODD. THE INSTRUCTION
;"CALL" WILL PUSH IN STACK THE ADDRESS OF THIS INSTRUCTION, THAT'S 
;HOW IT KNOWS HOW TO COME BACK HERE TO CONTINUE EXECUTION.
  call even_or_odd

;GET RESULT FROM STACK.
  pop  ax  

;DISPLAY RESULT.
  cmp  al, '1'
  je   even_number

;IF NO JUMP, AL == '0'.  
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset msj3
  int  21h           
  jmp  wait_for_key  ;SKIP "EVEN_NUMBER".
even_number:  
  mov  ah, 9
  mov  dx, offset msj2
  int  21h           

;WAIT FOR USER TO PRESS ANY KEY.
wait_for_key:
  mov  ah,7
  int  21h

;FINISH THE PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h           

;------------------------------------------
;THIS PROCEDURE RETURNS '1' IN STACK IF THE NUMBER
;IS EVEN OR '0' IF IT'S ODD.
;ASSUME THE NUMBER COMES IN BX.

proc even_or_odd
;DIVIDE NUMBER BY 2.    
  mov  ax, bx
  mov  bl, 2
  div  bl  ;AX / BL (NUMBER / 2). RESULT : QUOTIENT=AL, REMAINDER=AH.

;IF REMAINDER IS 0 THEN NUMBER IS EVEN, ELSE IT'S ODD.
  cmp  ah, 0
  je   its_even

;IF NO JUMP, IT'S ODD.
  mov  ax, '0'  ;VALUE TO STORE IN STACK.
  jmp  finish   ;SKIP "ITS_EVEN".
its_even:  
  mov  ax, '1'  ;VALUE TO STORE IN STACK.
finish:

;STORE VALUE IN STACK. IMPORTANT: WHEN THIS PROCEDURE
;WAS CALLED, THE RETURN ADDRESS WAS PUSHED IN STACK. TO
;RETURN THE VALUE IN STACK IT'S NECESSARY TO RETRIEVE
;THE RETURN ADDRESS FIRST, PUSH THE VALUE ('0' OR '1')
;AND PUSH THE RETURN ADDRESS BACK.
  pop  bx  ;RETRIEVE RETURN ADDRESS FROM THE CALL.
  push ax  ;VALUE TO RETURN ('0' OR '1').
  push bx  ;PUT RETURN ADDRESS BACK.

  ret  ;THIS "RET" POPS THE RETURN ADDRESS. THIS IS HOW
endp   ;IT KNOWS HOW TO RETURN WHERE THE PROC WAS CALLED.  

;------------------------------------------
;CONVERT STRING TO NUMBER IN BX.
;SI MUST ENTER POINTING TO THE STRING.

proc string2number
;MAKE SI TO POINT TO THE LEAST SIGNIFICANT DIGIT.
  inc  si ;POINTS TO THE NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED.
  mov  cl, [ si ] ;NUMBER OF CHARACTERS ENTERED.                                         
  mov  ch, 0 ;CLEAR CH, NOW CX==CL.
  add  si, cx ;NOW SI POINTS TO LEAST SIGNIFICANT DIGIT.

;CONVERT STRING.
  mov  bx, 0
  mov  bp, 1 ;MULTIPLE OF 10 TO MULTIPLY EVERY DIGIT.
repeat:
;CONVERT CHARACTER.                    
  mov  al, [ si ] ;CHARACTER TO PROCESS.
  sub  al, 48 ;CONVERT ASCII CHARACTER TO DIGIT.
  mov  ah, 0 ;CLEAR AH, NOW AX==AL.
  mul  bp ;AX*BP = DX:AX.
  add  bx,ax ;ADD RESULT TO BX. 
;INCREASE MULTIPLE OF 10 (1, 10, 100...).
  mov  ax, bp
  mov  bp, 10
  mul  bp ;AX*10 = DX:AX.
  mov  bp, ax ;NEW MULTIPLE OF 10.  
;CHECK IF WE HAVE FINISHED.
  dec  si ;NEXT DIGIT TO PROCESS.
  loop repeat ;COUNTER CX-1, IF NOT ZERO, REPEAT.

  ret 
endp    

;------------------------------------------
proc clear_screen
  mov  ah,0
  mov  al,3
  int  10H
  ret
endp
```

Notice the variable "str", used to capture the number from keyboard, uses the 3-DB format: the first DB specifies the max length (plus one for the ending chr(13)), another DB for the length of the string entered by user, and the third DB for the string itself.

Jester's is another solution for the problem. There's even a third solution : shifting the number to the right (instruction SHR), the dropped bit is stored in carry flag, then we can check if carry flag is 0 or 1 with instructions JC or JNC.

Comment: If I send parameters by the stack to the function,

Comment: when i write "ret'" in the of the function, dont the values become "junk"?   If I send parameters by the stack to the function, usually i have to white "ret" + the numbers of parameters ident*2 .if i want to return a value should I write "pop" to the parameters and pop the address, and than to push the answer and the address? what will happen when i write "ret+ number" ? Will the parameters be deleted from the stack and the anwer not?   and if I dont write pop to the parameters in the function , only the address, and push the answer and the address,  , should i write "ret +num"?

Comment: It's better not to mess with "ret".  I personally don't like to do things like "ret+num". You can add as many values to the stack as you want, just be carefull about popping and pushing back the return address from the "call". As long as you take care of the return address, everything will be fine. Those values won't be "junk" because the return addres is ON TOP of them, that's why the return address is the last thing we push on stack, so the "ret" will pop it first.

Comment: If i have for ex. 3 parameters+ answer+adress and i write "ret 6", will the anwer + 2  parameters will be deleted or the 3 parameters will be deleted? i mean, the stack contains 5 things. when i write ret 3, which of them will be deleted? the 3 under the adress or the 3 from the buttom of the stack?

Comment: And again- Thank you! Its so clear! and you anwer so patiently!

Comment: Here it is : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.asm.x86/Gh-hGhERSJ8 , and another : https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH11/CH11-4.html

Answer (score 2):

When a function returns a value on the stack, it is generally implemented by

1. removing all the values pushed in the calling sequence (stacked
   parameters, frame pointer and return address, saved registers), producing a clean stack with respect to the call site,
2. pushing the function value onto the clean stack,
3. and then exiting through the function return address.

One can implement these ideas straightforwardly, or one can do them in an optimized way.

Here is typical, straightforward code to do this:

```
call_site:  call get_number  ; assumed to eax
             push eax         ;  push argument onto the stack
             call is_even_or_odd
             pop  eax         ; get the function result back from the stack
             test eax, eax
             je   even
 odd:        ...


 is_even_or_odd:
             push   ebp        ; save frame pointer
             mov    eax, 8[ebp] ; get argument (above saved EBP and return address)
             and    eax, 1      ; now eax == 0 if even, 1 if odd

             pop    ebp         ; pop the push values from the stack
             pop    edx
             leas   4[esp]      ; pop the argument
             push   eax         ; push the result
             jmp    edx         ; go to the return address
```

The above routine is coded in a general way.  This specific routine could be coded more compactly, and have better performance:

```
 is_even_or_odd:
             ; no need to save frame pointer; just leave EBP alone
             pop    edx         ; get return address
             pop    eax         ; pop the argument
             and    eax, 1      ; now eax == 0 if even, 1 if odd
             push   eax         ; push the result
             push   edx         ; instead of "jmp edx"
             ret
```

The peculiar idiom at the end, of pushing the return address and then doing "ret" lets the hardware keep accurate track of return addresses in its shadow stack.  This means when it hits the ret instruction, it assumes the original return address is value (that's what it has in the shadow stack) and can start fetching instructions at the return point immediately.  The "jmp edx" idiom works, but breaks the branch address prediction, slowing down the time it takes to return from the subroutine.

One more variation uses the space in the call stack for arguments,
to return the result.  This works when the size of the arguments,
is equal to the size of the result, as it is in this example:

```
 is_even_or_odd:
             ; no need to save frame pointer; just leave EBP alone
             mov    eax, 4[esp] ; get the argument
             and    eax, 1      ; now eax == 0 if even, 1 if odd
             mov    4[esp], eax ; smash the argument with the result
             ret
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a particularly silly thing to do, but it's possible, of course.
If you get the input on the stack too, just replace it with the result.
Assuming 16 bit code, something like this:

```
push bp
mov bp, sp
and word [bp+4], 1 ; keep lowest bit
xor byte [bp+4], 1 ; flip it to return 1 for even
pop bp
ret
```

Comment: What's so silly about returning values on the stack? High level language compilers return structures on the stack. At least, they used to. Whereas it's perhaps silly in a production program to return a register-sized value on the stack, the technique for doing so is the same as for returning an arbitrarily large structure. It's a good learning exercise.

Comment: The conventions I know pass a hidden **input** argument using the applicable methods which point to a memory area for the return value. The value itself doesn't have to be on the stack. Messing with the caller's stack frame is not a good idea, especially if the arguments are freed by the caller and you have a return address on the stack (e.g. x86 stdcall).